# .Net Core Project on Linux Server

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, deployment, publish

I have completed my .Net Core project. As you can see in the picture below, I have published for linux. Now how do I send these publish files to the server? I decided to give it a try on xammp. I put the Publish files in the htdocs folder in xampp. Now I ran the apache server. But my project is not working and the folder directory is coming. How do I run my project on the server?

[image: my publish settings]

[image: The path where I copied the files]

[image: result on xampp]

Comment: Please follow this article to deploy .net core project on linux apache server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-7.0